# android, extract value from long string

Tags: java, android, search, design-patterns

I have a long string that I want to parse and retrieve a value.
I was thinking of using patterns but I am a bit rusty at this.

This is the part of the string that interests me:

> ...sinking will be 44% successful...

the word 'sinking' is the keyword. I am looking to get the percentage value(44% in this case)

What is the best way?
Thank you.

** the words 'will be' may change.

Comment: Only two options, stringtokenize/split (or) expressions. You need to chose one of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a regex solution:

```
String str = "...sinking will be 44% successful...";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "sinking will be (\\S*) successful" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( str );
if ( m.find() ) {
    String percent = m.group( 1 );
}
```

If you want just the numeral value of the percent, change your pattern to this:

```
"sinking will be (\\d*)% successful"
```

If any of the preceding text is irrelevant, you just want to grab the percent in a line, use this pattern:

```
"(\\d*%)"
```

Edit: If your keyword is "sinking", and you want the first percentage value after this word, this would be your pattern:

```
"sinking(?:[\\w\\s]*) (\\d+%)"
```

Comment: thanks Jason. But there are a few other percentages before and after this text. so I dont think this will work.

Comment: Do you know exactly how many? If not, what word(s) make this percentage special from the rest of them? How would you pick this one out?

Comment: exactly this Jason. I am looking the first percentage after my keyword:) thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution if it is always THIS kind of string:

```
String splitMe = "...sinking will be 44% successful...";
String strPercents = splitMe.split(" ")[3];
System.out.println(strPercents);//test output
```

Otherwise: good regex ressource
http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html#examples

Comment: thanks thomas. But i think this will not work(would it?) because this is just the part that interests me. before and after this there are a lots of other stuff, hence the ...

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the text will always start with "sinking will be " and a % will always be there this will work regardless of the text surrounding it

```
String s = "more text more text sinking will be 44% successful more text";
String find = "sinking will be ";
int findIndex = s.indexOf(find) + find.length();
int pctIndex = s.indexOf("%", findIndex);

String result = s.substring(findIndex , pctIndex);
```

Comment: unfortunately only the word "sinking' is certain to be there.

Comment: I just noticed you edited your post that the text "will be" may not always be there. In that case this won't work. Your best bet will be to use a regex